# Duplicate object creation with nested transactions using spring,hibernate and mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, transactions

I have two services, like this (simplified code):

```
@Service
public class OuterService {

  @Autowired
  InnerService innerService;

  @Transactional
  public void doSomething() {
      List<SomeEntity> list = entityRepo.findByWhatever(...);
      for(SomeEntity listElement : list) {
          innerService.processEntity(listElement);
      }
  }
}


@Service
public class InnerService {

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void processEntity(Entity entity) {
       // ...
       StatusElement status = new StatusElement(...);
       statusElementRepo.save(status);
    }

}
```

The constructed `StatusElement` is now inserted by exiting `InnerService.processEntity()` and **inserted again** by exiting `OuterService.doSomething()`.

If I change the `@Transactional` annotation of `OuterService.doSomething()` to `@Transactional(readOnly = true)`, it is inserted just once.

Is it a problem with MySql (because it may not support nested transactions), do I need a special transaction manager, or is there something wrong with my code? TIA!

Comment: Hibernate does not support nested transactions as such, and REQUIRES_NEW is NOT a nested transaction, just a separate one.
The code doesn't show if or how the Entity and the StatusElement entities interact. If they do (like adding a status into a list of statuses in the Entity), and the two services in fact work with distinct Sessions (due to the transaction handling), you could be leaking the StatusElement objects from  the processEntity Session into the Session of doSomething, causing an automatic persist there as well as your explicit 'save()'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using programmatically transactions using the `PlatformTransactionManager`.

see: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-programmatic-ptm